# How to: compare array with string and create hastags before tweeting

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have the following array (which is the returned value of a database query):

```
Array ( [0] => PHP [1] => Webdesign [2] => Wordpress [3] => Drupal [4])
```

And the following string:

> Working With Wordpress Shortcodes

How can I compare the array with the string to see if the string contains any word stored in the array? (hopefully that made sense to you :d )

When he finds a match (eg: Wordpress) it should create a hashtag like so:

> Working With #Wordpress Shortcodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`:

```
$tags = array('PHP', 'Webdesign', 'Wordpress', 'Drupal', 'SQL');
$text = 'Working With Wordpress Shortcodes and doing some NoSQL and SQL';

$regex = '/\b('.implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $tags)).')\b/i';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '#$1', $text);
```

Would output:

> Working With [#Wordpress](http://#Wordpress) Shortcodes and doing some NoSQL and [#SQL](http://#SQL)

Live example:

> http://codepad.org/SxchtXmI

Comment: nice thanks, I'll have a look at it later. I did use preg_replace but not properly i think

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the array and run [preg_replace](http://uk.php.net/preg_replace) over the string for each value (making sure to check for word boundaries in the regular expression (e.g. so car doesn't match cartoon)

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through your array and use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) (or its case-insensitive version [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos)):

```
$tags = array('PHP', 'Webdesign', 'Wordpress', 'Drupal');
$message = "Working With Wordpress Shortcodes";

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $position = strpos($message, $tag);

    if ($position !== false) {
        // tag found! add # in front.
        $message = substr($message, 0, $position).'#'.substr($message, $position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using strpos has the negative effect that it will match partial words, e.g. `SQL` would match `MySQL` and that would become `My#SQL`. Using regular expressions with word boundaries would work a lot better and produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$working_array = array('PHP','Webdesign','Wordpress','Drupal');
$string = "Working With Wordpress Shortcodes";
foreach($working_array as $array_item)
{
    $the_pos = stripos($string,$array_item);
    if($the_pos !== false)
    {
        $string = substr($string,0,$the_pos) . '#' . substr($string,$the_pos);
    }
}
echo $string;
?>
```

**Edited because I accidentally mixed some C syntax in!  Sorry!**

Answer (score 0):

May take much processing time (I guess) if your array is big

```
$hashtags = array('Wordpress', 'Twitter', 'Joomla', 'Google');
$content = "A tweet containing wordpress and joomla";


$content_breakdown = explode(' ', $content);
foreach ($hashtags as $hashtag) {

    foreach ($content_breakdown as & $word) {
        if (strtolower($word) == strtolower($hashtag))
            $word = '#' . $word;
    }
}

$content = implode($content_breakdown, ' ');
echo $content;
```

#### Output

```
A tweet containing #wordpress and #joomla
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hashtags = array('Wordpress', 'Joomla', /* ... */ );
$tweet = "This is a tweet containing Wordpress and Joomlazoom as hashtag";

$hashtags_tmp = implode('|', $hashtags);
$tweet = preg_replace("/\b($hashtags_tmp)\b/i", '#$1', $tweet);
```